# How to use redux-form in peer dependency

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, rollup

I am trying to create a ES6 module of a login form using rollup and react-redud.

I have a rollup with the following configuration:

```
const plugins = [
  // Unlike Webpack and Browserify, Rollup doesn't automatically shim Node
  // builtins like `process`. This ad-hoc plugin creates a 'virtual module'
  // which includes a shim containing just the parts the bundle needs.
  {
    resolveId(importee) {
      if (importee === processShim) return importee;
      return null;
    },
    load(id) {
      if (id === processShim) return 'export default { argv: [], env: {} }';
      return null;
    },
  },
  nodeResolve(),
  commonjs({
    include: 'node_modules/**',
    namedExports: {
      './node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js': ['fromJS', 'Map', 'List', 'Record', 'Iterable'],
      './node_modules/redux/dist/redux.js': ['createStore', 'combineReducers', 'bindActionCreators', 'applyMiddleware', 'compose'],
      './node_modules/react-redux/dist/react-redux.js': [' Provider', 'createProvider', 'connectAdvanced', 'connect'],
    },
  }),
  replace({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(prod ? 'production' : 'development'),
  }),
  inject({
    process: processShim,
  }),
  json(),
  babel({
    plugins: ['external-helpers'],
    exclude: 'node_modules/**',
  }),
  cleanup(),
];

if (prod) plugins.push(uglify(), visualizer({ filename: './bundle-stats.html' }));

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  sourcemap: true,
  name: pkg.name,
  external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'prop-types', 'styled-components', 'bootstrap-styled', 'classnames', 'react-transition-group', 'loaders', 'redux-form', 'redux', 'react-redux', 'react-intl', 'message-common', 'bootstrap-styled-motion'],
  exports: 'named',
  output,
  plugins,
  globals: { react: 'React', 'react-dom': 'ReactDom', 'prop-types': 'PropTypes', 'styled-components': 'styled', classnames: 'cn', 'react-transition-group': 'ReactTransitionGroup', loaders: 'loaders', 'redux-form': 'redux-form', 'react-intl': 'react-intl', 'message-common': 'message-common' },
};
```

My rollup bundle fine, no warnings.

I have tried every possibility of import :

```
import reduxForm from 'redux-form/lib/immutable/reduxForm';
import Field from 'redux-form/lib/immutable/Field';
```

and

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form/es/immutable';
```

and

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form/es/immutable';
```

But nothing work, everytime I install this module somewhere, the transpiled ES  replace this line with these imports

```
import reactRedux from 'react-redux';
import redux from 'redux';
```

I assume this is happening because **redux-form** depend on these two. Because these two modules doesn't have **default export**, this throw an error :

> WARNING in ./node_modules/login-form/dist/login-form.es.js
>   3471:19-24 "export 'default' (imported as 'redux') was not found in 'redux'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/login-form/dist/login-form.es.js
>   3524:26-36 "export 'default' (imported as 'reactRedux') was not found in 'react-redux'

I have tried to play with `globals`, `namedExports`. I haven't found a way to make **redux-form** a peer of my project.

Comment: ```Instead of import myModule from 'my-module'; try using import myModule from 'node_modules/my-module/dist/my-module.js'.``` https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/206/

Comment: I finally solved it and I had to setmy externals with `redux-form/immutable` instead of just `redux-form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it and I had to set my externals with `redux-form/immutable` instead of just `redux-form`